# Disable inheritance on new folders?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, document-library, permissions, 2019

I have a goal. On the root of document library in Sharepoint, users should be able to create their own items, like folders (edit). When user creates his/her folder, only that user should be able to access and edit the folder and have full control permission over the folder. In other words, the inheritance should be automatically disabled and initial permissions would be only full control to it's owner.

By now, we need to turn off inheritance manually for every folder and delete users and groups, it the scenario above possible in Sharepoint?

We are using Sharepoint 2019.

Comment: Maybe you need to write a workflow/power automate flow on item/folder creation and break the inheritance in flow and grant the permissions to only folder creator.

Answer (score 0):

Here are artciles about breaking item permission inheritance/removing item permission/adding item permission using SharePoint Workflow And REST API for your reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/breaking-item-permission-inheritance-using-sharepoint-workflow-and-rest-api/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/removing-item-permission-using-sharepoint-workflow-and-rest-api/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-new-item-permission-using-sharepoint-workflow-and-rest-api/